# R shiny, write data table

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am working with shiny on a server. I want to read a table from a URL and then write to the directory as a CSV file and the read it from the directory. I can not write it to my directory... here is the simplified code:

UI:

```
library(shiny)
library(XML)
library(shinydashboard)





dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "BLA BLA BLA"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
 DT::dataTableOutput("datatable")
  )

         )
```

Server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(XML)

function(input, output){
geodatasetInput <- observe({
url <- "http://www.fipiran.com/Fund/MFComparing/1"
url2 <- "http://www.fipiran.com/Market/LupBourse"
classes <- c("character", "FormattedNumber", "Percent", "FormattedNumber","Percent", "integer","FormattedNumber", "FormattedNumber", "FormattedNumber", "numeric","FormattedNumber", "numeric" ,"numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")
ss <- readHTMLTable(url2, which = 1, colClasses = classes, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.csv(ss, "ss.csv")
})



output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({
url <- "http://www.fipiran.com/Fund/MFComparing/1"
url2 <- "http://www.fipiran.com/Market/LupBourse"

classes <- c("character", "FormattedNumber", "Percent", "FormattedNumber","Percent", "integer","FormattedNumber", "FormattedNumber", "FormattedNumber", "numeric","FormattedNumber", "numeric" ,"numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")
ss <- readHTMLTable(url2, which = 1, colClasses = classes, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DT::datatable(ss, options = list(lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
        pageLength = 5,
        list(scrollX = TRUE),
                                autoWidth = TRUE,
  columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))
                                ))



})


}
```

Comment: What do you mean you can't write? Are you getting a permisson error? Is the app crashing?

Comment: I am not sure whether my code is wrong or what makes it crash!
but the fact is that it does not run!
is there any problem with the code?

Comment: My guess is that the `shiny` user does not have writing permissions on the folder where the app is located. Does everything work fine when you run it without shiny-server?

Comment: How could you allow `shiny` to have writing permissions? I'm making a shiny app as part of an R package, and I want to be able to read and write csvs on users local computers.

Answer (score 0):

I restructured the code a little bit, so that the website is only parsed once. However, the other code also worked for me. So maybe, you have a file ss.csv, that is already opened?

Silke

```
    data <- reactiveValues()

      observe({
        url <- "http://www.fipiran.com/Fund/MFComparing/1"
        url2 <- "http://www.fipiran.com/Market/LupBourse"
        classes <- c("character", "FormattedNumber", "Percent", "FormattedNumber","Percent", "integer","FormattedNumber", "FormattedNumber", "FormattedNumber", "numeric","FormattedNumber", "numeric" ,"numeric", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")
        data$ss <- readHTMLTable(url2, which = 1, colClasses = classes, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
write.csv(data$ss,"ss.csv")

      })



      output$datatable <- DT::renderDataTable({

        DT::datatable(data$ss, options = list(lengthMenu = list(c(5, 15, -1), c('5', '15', 'All')),
                                         pageLength = 5,
                                         list(scrollX = TRUE),
                                         autoWidth = TRUE,
                                         columnDefs = list(list(width = '100px', targets = "_all"))
        ))



      })
```

Comment: I am working on a remote server, and I do not know what is wrong with the code!
however, it runs properly on a local system and writes the CSV file on the directory!

Comment: the problem is with permission